# How to read a table from filename received as argument in R?

Tags: r

I was trying to read a table in R using an argument received from a php  program like,

echo exec("Rscript /var/www/html/genome/coex.R  $db");

In R,

```
 args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=FALSE)
 db <-  args[1]
 db <-paste(db, "txt", sep=".") 

dat <- as.matrix(read.table("/var/www/html/genome/coex_db/db", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
```

I am not sure how can the filename  for the **db** can be used to get the table content in **dat**.

Comment: Try instead `db <- paste0("/var/www/html/genome/coex_db/", db, ".txt")`.

Comment: Donjin : path to your `db` should be either relative to path of this script or pass complete path name

Comment: That change of code didn't work @RuiBarradas

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you correctly @parth

Comment: @Donjin, i meant that _file_ argument to `read.table` function is a valid path in environment of script.

Comment: Does the file exist under that name? Try `list.files(path/to/file, db)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  It was my mistake from my side. Your previous solution was working. My apologies. I could have mark it as answered it it was in the answer section.